# Schedule Power On/Off (not the restart)

Tags: applications

Is there any 3ed party application to SCHEDULE POWER ON /OFF that is  compatible with any of the Samsung mobile phones or other Android phones which doesn't have this function build in?

AUTOMATEIT PRO app - would it do the schedule power on/ off?

Thanks a lot in advance☺️

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Sorry, but device recommendation is off-topic here. You might be interested in our sister site, Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange, but please ensure to follow [their guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205) to get the best device for your need.

Comment: any device can do it. set alarm it will ask about keeping alarm active while powered off and alarm should wake up device. but no device exist that will unlock sim pin without user interaction, therefore one can't receive calls. also the behavior turning on on charger is just a setting any android device is cabable of. so basically all it needs is some automation app like MacroDroid (if no native option already exist) https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=scheduled+power+on

Comment: Sorry, while the question has been edited from device recommendations, as of current writing, it looks like asking for app recommendations, which are also off-topic. We prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details, and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.